# clicking on a library to import on arduino creates blank line in arduino sketch

Tags: arduino, libraries

I have a sketch that I am trying tin use Time.h in or DateTime.h. I have imported the libraries and they show up in the list on libraries. when I click on ether of them they just ad a blank line to my sketch. if I try to add it myself like #include  then try to access part of the library I get an error telling me the item I am trying to access is not defined. I can see the Time and DateTime folders in the libraries folder. and can see them as a options in the import Library menu. 
Please help.
Danny

Answer (score 0):

Just remove library from

```
Documents\Arduino\libraries\DateTime\
```

and copy lib manually from zip file.